# Thread.start() prints 0 on the console

Tags: java, multithreading

I cant figure out why the following line of code prints on the console

```
new Thread(this).start()
```

this output:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWoiZ.png

This is a Runnable object.

Further debugging made me realize that it seems to be connected to the start0() method in the .start()

Comment: Have you tried using (new Thread(new RunnableClass())).start()?

Comment: Show your run() method, the problem likely lies there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line will cause the `run()` method of the `Runnable` to be executed; presumably that method prints this output.

Comment: Well that was embarrassing, you were absolutely right thank you for the quick answer